# Реализация слайдера на чистом JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Недавно освоил теоретические основы JS и решил закрепить знания сделав слайдер.

```js
var slide_left = document.getElementById('left'),
  slide_right = document.getElementById('right'),
  images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
  idx = 1;

slide_right.addEventListener('click', moveLeft);

function moveLeft() {
  slide_left.style.display = 'block';
  images[idx].style.display = 'none';
  images[++idx].style.display = 'block';
  if (idx === images.length - 1) {
    slide_right.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

slide_left.addEventListener('click', moveRight);

function moveRight() {
  slide_right.style.display = 'block';
  images[idx].style.display = 'none';
  images[--idx].style.display = 'none';
  if (idx === 0) {
    slide_left.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
.slides {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 10;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

.showing {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.cont_button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#left,
#right {
  font-size: 50px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  border-radius: 14px;
  background-color: #d6b511;
  color: black;
  transition: .1s all;
}

#left:hover,
#right:hover {
  background-color: #ccff00;
}

#first_wallpaper,
#second_wallpaper,
#three_wallpaper {}
```

```html
<ul class="slides">
  <li class="slide">
    <img id="first_wallpaper" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/000000/red" alt="">
  </li>
  <li class="slide">
    <img id="second_wallpaper" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/000000/green" alt="">
  </li>
  <li class="slide">
    <img id="three_wallpaper" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/000000/blue" alt="">
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="cont_button">
  <button id="left">left</button>
  <button id="right">right</button>
</div>
```

Код очень простой, часть взял с этого же сайта, а часть написал сам. Проблема в том, что как я понимаю необходимо прицепить индекс четко к каждой картинке, в голову ничего не приходит, логику понимаю а реализовать не выходит.

Comment: кода много, вникать лень. вопрос в чём? 1)как сгенерировать id'шники ? 2) как перебрать картинки, без  id'шников?

Comment: Вопрос в том, что есть индекс значение которого меняется при клике на стрелку, и мне нужно понять как к каждому из 3 значений индекса (3 значения ибо 3 фото на слайдере) прицепить свою картинку.

Comment: У вас точно корректный код? Если нажать выполнить код, то не отображаются картинки и кнопки. Что должно происходить при нажатие на кнопку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Код очень простой..." Это да... Но, тут попроще будет разобраться, думаю.

```js
var slide_left = document.getElementById('left'),
  slide_right = document.getElementById('right'),
  images = document.getElementsByTagName('li'),
  idx = 2;

function fShowHide() {
  images[idx].className = 'show';
  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    if (i != idx) {
      images[i].className = 'hide';
    };
  }
}

slide_left.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.disabled = (idx == 1);
  idx--;
  fShowHide();
  slide_right.disabled = false;
});

slide_right.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.disabled = (idx == images.length - 2);
  idx++;
  fShowHide();
  slide_left.disabled = false;
});

fShowHide();
```

```css
.slides {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #333;
}

.slides li {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  transition: 1.5s all;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 100%;
  transition: .8s all;
}

.cont_button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#left,
#right {
  color: #050;
  margin: 15px;
  transition: .2s all;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 36px;
}

#left:hover,
#right:hover {
  color: #a00;
}

#left:disabled,
#right:disabled {
  color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<ul class="slides">
  <li>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/ffaaaa/ffffff?text=1%20первая" alt="">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/ffcc66/ffffff?text=2" alt="">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/bbbbbb/444444?text=3%20середина" alt="">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/66bb66/ffffff?text=4" alt="">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/6666bb/ffffff?text=5%20последняя" alt="">
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="cont_button">
  <button id="left">&#9668;</button>
  <button id="right">&#9658;</button>
</div>
```

Теория - это хорошо, но практика - наше всё))